# How to disable html required validation when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript

**I have this existing function:** When checkbox is unchecked it will show the `ul` section

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb_ship" onclick="toggle('.ship', this)" checked="checked">

  <label for="cb_ship" >Same as account name</label>



 <form method="post">  
      <ul class="ship" style="display:none;">
       <li> fname <input type="text" name="fname" required></li>
       <li> lname <input type="text" name="lname" required></li>
       <li> age <input type="text" name="age" required></li>
       <li> address <input type="text" name="address" required></li>
       <li> city <input type="text" name="city" required></li>
       <li> <input type="submit" value="send"></li>
      </ul>
  </form>
```

JS:

```
function toggle(className, obj) {
        var $input = $(obj);

        if ($input.prop('checked'))
            $(className).hide();
        else $(className).show();
    }
```

**What I want to do:** If the checkbox is checked, all the required attributes should be disabled *without clicking the checkbox*. So, I can submit the form.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the required attributes from the elements? Why do you need them as long as the ul is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

your function will be like this

```
  function toggle(className, obj) {
  var attr = false;
    if  (obj.is(':checked')){
        attr = true;
    }
    $("."+className+" li input").each(function(){
        $(this).prop('disabled', attr);
    });
}
```

but in the checkbox you have to remove the dot (.ship) cuase it will make an error and add the $ for the object onclick="toggle('ship', $(this))

Comment: Where should I place this? Inside the `if` of my condition?

Comment: I removed the dot (.) and now my hide and show didn't work

Answer (score 0):

remove the attribute?

```
$('.ship').find('input').removeAttr( "required");
```

OR disable the inputs?

```
$('.ship').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Both

```
$('.ship').find('input').removeAttr( "required").prop('disabled', true);
```

Use them like so:

```
function toggle(className, obj) {
    var $input = $(obj);
    if ($input.prop('checked'))
        $(className).hide().find('input').removeAttr("required").prop('disabled', true);
    else $(className).show().find('input').attr( "required",true).prop('disabled', false);
}
```

To handle the situation where you wish to process the logic on page startup due to the "required" being set at that point, remove the handler from the markup, put it in code then trigger it:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_ship" checked="checked">
<label for="cb_ship">Same as account name</label>
<form method="post">
  <ul class="ship" style="display:none;">
    <li> fname
      <input type="text" name="fname" required>
    </li>
    <li> lname
      <input type="text" name="lname" required>
    </li>
    <li> age
      <input type="text" name="age" required>
    </li>
    <li> address
      <input type="text" name="address" required>
    </li>
    <li> city
      <input type="text" name="city" required>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="submit" value="send">
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

See the last portion where I trigger the handler:

```
function toggle(className, obj) {
  var $input = $(obj);
  if ($input.prop('checked')) {
    console.log("checked");
    $(className).hide().find('input').removeAttr("required").prop('disabled', true);
  } else $(className).show().find('input').attr("required", true).prop('disabled', false);
}
$('#cb_ship').on('click change', function() {
  toggle('.ship', this);
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Your code worked sir. But, my bad I have an error. How can activate function w/o clicking the checkbox. Because it happened that I need to check and uncheck the checkbox before it will disable the `required` attr.

Comment: `toggle('.ship', $('#cb_ship'))` or `toggle('.ship', '#cb_ship')`  Note the the in-line onclick you have might be better as an event handler instead (in code) as `$('#cb_ship').on('click change', function(){toggle('.ship',this);});`

Comment: The `ul` section is not displayed by default. So, it means that the `required` attributes are not yet disabled coz I'm not clicking the checkbox. So, I cannot submit the form because it will read the `required` attribute. I want to achieve is if checkbox is checked the required attribute will be disabled. PS: I updated the question :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Be sure to remove the `console.log` prior to deployment  if you use this.